# Unable to Initialize Jquery Sly

Tags: sly-scroller

I can't seem to get Sly to initialize, no matter what changes I make.  I also keep getting an error on line 439 of sly.js.

At first I thought it was just an issue with testing locally, until I encountered the same error in jsFiddle.

Here is the fiddle I made.  http://jsfiddle.net/8NxXR/

and here's the code:

HTML markup

```
<div class='frame' id="headshots">
    <ul class="slidee">
        <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/szX5beD.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/szX5beD.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/szX5beD.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/szX5beD.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/szX5beD.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="scrollbar">
    <div class="handle"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
        $scrollBar = $('.scrollbar');
        $frame = $('#headshots');

        var sly = new Sly($frame, {         

            horizontal: 1,
            itemNav: 'forceCentered',
            smart: 1,
            activateOn: 'click',
            mouseDragging: 1,
            touchDragging: 1,
            releaseSwing: 1,
            startAt: 3,
            scrollBar: $scrollBar,
            scrollBy: 1,
            speed: 300,
            elasticBounds: 1,
            easing: 'easeOutExpo',
            dragHandle: 1,
            dynamicHandle: 1,
            clickBar: 1

        }).init();

        sly.activate(3);


    });
```

Any ideas?